# How to show a confirm dialog when selecting an item in easy ui combobox

Tags: events, combobox, dialog, jquery-easyui

I would like to do something with easy ui combobox like following:
  Ask the user to confirm or cancel selection before the item being really selected, if the user choose 'confirm', select what he/she wants to select; otherwise, stay where the selection was

The dialog pop up step is done, what puzzled me is how I can get the oldValue, ie. the previous selection. if I use the onChange method, I can only get the value of the previous selection, however, what I accatually want is the record! I need not only the value information, please, someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one,

```
var oldval;
<input id="cc1" class="easyui-combobox" data-options="  
    valueField: 'id',  
    textField: 'text',  
    url: 'get_data1.php',  
    onSelect: function(rec){  
        $.messager.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure to select this item', function(r)
        {
         if (r){
              oldval=rec.key
          }
         else{
    $('#cc1').combobox('setValue', oldval);
     }
        }); 

    }" />
```